# How restrictions reduce the number of possible arrangements

Tags: combinatorics

A company has five departments. The company is establishing a board consisting of five members that represent a distinct department each. Suppose that every employee is a candidate to represent his department in the board. As every employee belonging to a department is distinguishable, we can see that without any further restriction the number of different possible people arrangements in the board is simply the multiplication of employee numbers of the five departments. However, the company has figured out that there are some “incompatible” pairs that prevent two persons in each pair to sit together in the board (e.g. John from Production dept and Alexandra from Sales dept are incompatible, Amy from Administration dept and Anna from Accounting dept are incompatible, Anna from Accounting dept is also incompatible with David from Sales dept, and so on).  With such restrictions, how do we now compute the number of different possible people arrangements? Is there any established formula or algorithm dealing with this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that a general approach to these types of problems is to over-count and then remove the duplicates. So the total number of possible arrangements is, as you said, the product of each department's employee count. Now if John is picked from Production, and he can't work with 5 others, then this removes 5 of the arrangements. Now you must remember not to subtract John's incompatibility more than once. So if John and Alexandra were not compatible, when you are checking on Alexandra's compatibility, you must not subtract her incompatibility with John again. From here you can see how you would write an algorithm to do this sort of thing, keeping track of the total possible combinations.